# Save original image from PictureBox, not resized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

Is it possible to save original image with original quality from PictureBox, not the stretched/resized one? I download byte array from a server and put it in PictureBox, I want user to be able to save the actual image, but it should be the original image (original quality and original size) I received from the HTTP server, not resized and reduced quality one that I show in a PictureBox. Is it possible or do I have to store the byte array I receive from server somewhere in order to achieve this?

Comment: `Image` property of the `PictureBox` contains the original image, while the control may paint the image as zoom/resized/stretched depending to its `SizeMode`. So, just save the `Image` property and it will be the same image which you had read from database.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, are you 100% sure? If so, pictureBox.Image.Save would do the job you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of the `PictureBox` contains the original image, while the control may paint the image as zoom/resized/stretched depending to its `SizeMode`. You can see the source code for the property [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,f67adf711ae5bec3). 
 Just save the `Image` property and it will be the same image which you had read from database.

So calling `pictureBox1.Image.Save` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The rub with using `pictureBox.Image.Save` is that it doesn't save the background.  So I wound up using:

```
 //create a Bitmap from the pictureBox1 background Image:
  using Bitmap saveBMP = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.BackgroundImage);

 // create a new Graphics instance to draw on:
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(saveBMP))

 // fill in bitmap from pictureBox's Image layer
  g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image,0,0); 

 // and finally, save it off:
  saveBMP.Save(saveImage.FileName);
```

Hope this saves you some sanity--it took me a bit of screwing around to get it right!